# Gtk3 Calendar month change arrow size

Tags: css, user-interface, gtk3

How can I change size of Gtk3 month-change indicator/arrow.

[image]

I've tried to change it with css class GtkCalendar.button but with no response. Also there is no information about this indicator in GtkCalendar Gnome Developer documentation.

Comment: Try examining it with the Inspector (start program with `GTK_DEBUG=interactive`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The `GTK_DEBUG=interactive` show only one element `GtkCalendar` ther was no info about arrows.

Comment: Check the "CSS nodes" view in the inspector.

Comment: @ptomato Again thank you for the answer. I've checked 'CSS nodes' last time. There is only one element `GtkCalendar`.